# Jquery menu not show sub ul for mvc partial view

Tags: jquery, asp.net-mvc, jquery-ui, asp.net-mvc-partialview

i'm try to use this sample for my menu :

http://jqueryui.com/menu/#default

my code:

```
@model VirtualWebStore.Models.MainProductCategoryModel
<link rel="stylesheet" href="//code.jquery.com/ui/1.11.1/themes/ui-darkness/jquery-ui.css">
<script src="//code.jquery.com/jquery-1.10.2.js"></script>
<script src="//code.jquery.com/ui/1.11.1/jquery-ui.js"></script>
<script>
    $(document).ready(function () {

        $("#menu").menu();

    });

</script>
<div>
    <div class=" pull-right">
        <ul id="menu">
            <li class="ui-state-disabled">MENU</li>
            @foreach (var item in Model.Categorylst)
            {
                <li>
                    <a href="#">
                        @Html.DisplayFor(x => item.CategoryName)
                    </a>
                </li>
                foreach (var subtoCat in Model.CategoryToSub)
                {
                    if (item.CategoryId == subtoCat.CategoryId)
                    {
                        foreach (var sub in Model.SubCategorylst)
                        {
                            if (sub.SubCategoryId == subtoCat.SubCategoryId)
                            {
                <ul>

                    <li>
                        <a href="#">@Html.DisplayFor(x => sub.SubCategoryName)</a>
                    </li>
                </ul>
                            }
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
        </ul>
    </div>
</div>
```

the model - mainproductcategory:

```
public class MainProductCategoryModel
    {
        WebStoreEntities1 db = new WebStoreEntities1();

        public Product product { get; set; }
        public CategoryModel category { get; set; }
        public SubCategoryModel subCategory { get; set; }

        public IEnumerable<CategoryToSubCategory> CategoryToSub
        {
            get
            {
                return db.CategoryToSubCategories.ToList();
            }
        }

        public IEnumerable<SubCategory> SubCategorylst
        {
            get
            {

                return db.SubCategories.ToList();
            }
        }

        public IEnumerable<Product> Productlst
        {
            get
            {
                return db.Products.ToList();
            }
        }

        public IEnumerable<Category> Categorylst
        {
            get
            {
                return db.Categories.ToList();
            }
        }

    }
}
```

im new at mvc and jquery. 
im using forech lops becouse in my website the user can add the category and sub-category dynamic and i save it all in sql table.

the problam is that i see only category name and i cant see the sub categories when i use jquery.
i see all categories and sub categories ok witout jquery.

this HTML is a partial view.

the model is take the details from the DB .

in the sql tables i have : 
1 - prdoucts
2- categpry
3- sub category 
4 -Category to SubCategory (that have all this tables ID'S)

in the website the manager can added categories , sub categories and products. 
in the home page / manger page he see all products and he can editing them.

the menu HTML use this model the get all categories and sub categories from the DB. all this html is a partial view that i put in shard/layout.

Comment: Would be very helpful to see your MainProductCategoryModel class, and what is actually showing on your website.

Comment: Are you seeing any errors in the JavaScript console? Since you're using jQuery and this is a partial, it's possible you're trying to call the menu function before the jQuery library has actually been loaded.

Comment: i dont see any errors at the console. i use jquery at this html page at the beginig before i use the function menu:  
<link rel="stylesheet" href="//code.jquery.com/ui/1.11.1/themes/ui-darkness/jquery-ui.css">
<script src="//code.jquery.com/jquery-1.10.2.js"></script>
<script src="//code.jquery.com/ui/1.11.1/jquery-ui.js"></script>

Comment: So you're loading jQuery in the `<head>`, then?

Comment: i loading at the partial html itself.

Comment: i added to my code here the jQuery as i use it on the Html page.
you can see it now.

Answer (score 0):

ok 
i fund the answer. 
i had some confusion with the ul & il

so the answer is:

```
   <ul id="menu">
        <li class="ui-state-disabled">menu</li>
        @foreach (var item in Model.Categorylst)
        {
            <li>
                <a href="#">
                    @Html.DisplayFor(x => item.CategoryName)
                </a>
            </li>
            <li>
                <ul>
                    @foreach (var subtoCat in Model.CategoryToSub)
                    {
                        if (item.CategoryId == subtoCat.CategoryId)
                        {

                            foreach (var sub in Model.SubCategorylst)
                            {
                                if (sub.SubCategoryId == subtoCat.SubCategoryId)
                                {

                        <li>
                            <a href="#">@Html.DisplayFor(x => sub.SubCategoryName)</a>
                        </li>

                                }
                            }

                        }
                    }
                </ul>
            </li>
        }
    </ul>
```